# Wrong proof of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous at $0$ such that $f(x)+f(2x/3)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, functional-equations

> Find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous at $0$ such that $f(x)+f(2x/3)=x$.

Assume by contradiction that such a function exists. Hence, setting $x=0$, it is $f(0)=0$ and so, by the continuity at $x=0$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $-\epsilon<f(x)<\epsilon$ for any $x\in(-\delta_\epsilon,\delta_\epsilon)$.

Since $|2x/3|\le|x|$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ it is $-\epsilon<f(2x/3)<\epsilon$ for any $x\in(-\delta_\epsilon,\delta_\epsilon)$ as well. Summing the inequalities, for any $\epsilon>0$ it is $-2\epsilon<f(x)+f(2x/3)<2\epsilon$ for any $x\in(-\delta_\epsilon,\delta_\epsilon)$.

Since $\delta_\epsilon>0$, it is $0<\delta_\epsilon/2<\delta_\epsilon$ and so the inequality above must hold for $x=\delta_\epsilon/2$ as well; so $-2\epsilon<f(\delta_\epsilon/2)+f\left(\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{\delta_\epsilon}{2}\right)<2\epsilon$. But it is $f(x)+f(2x/3)=x$, hence $f(\delta_\epsilon/2)+f\left(\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{\delta_\epsilon}{2}\right)=\delta_\epsilon/2$ and so it is $-2\epsilon<\delta_\epsilon/2<2\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. This is a contradiction, because this should hold for any $\epsilon>0$ and so, in particular, for $\epsilon=\delta_\epsilon/8$ too; but this latter choice leads to $1/2<1/4$.

This is surely wrong, since $f(x)=3x/5$ is a solution. Where is my proof wrong? Is it wrong because $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$, and so I can't choose a $\epsilon$ dependent on $\delta$?

Comment: You have identified the problem correctly, you can't make $\epsilon$ a function of $\delta$ when $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$. Changing $\epsilon$ leads to a new $\delta$.

Comment: @Zarrax thank you for your help :) so, for instance, if it was $f(x)+f(2x/3)=t_0$ with $t_0>0$ fixed, with the same reasoning I would had $-2\epsilon<t_0<2\epsilon$ and this would have been a contradiction choosing (this time, legitimately) $\epsilon=t_0/2$?

Comment: That gives a contradiction to the statement that $f(0) = 0$. But you can have $f(0) = {3 \over 5} t_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no contradiction. Note $\epsilon$ is first chosen and "fixed", then you choose $\delta$, which usually depends on the $\epsilon$ you previously chose, so $\delta=\delta_\epsilon=\delta(\epsilon)$

Go back to your work:
$$-2\epsilon<\delta_\epsilon/2<2\epsilon$$
Up to here, you could think $\epsilon$ is fixed already, for example, $\epsilon=0.1$, then you choose $\delta_\epsilon$, for example, $\delta_{0.1}=0.08$, and it satisfies above inequality.

Next, when you choose $\epsilon=\delta_\epsilon/8$, it means your "new-epsilon" $\epsilon'$ equals your "old-delta" over $8$,

$$\text{Namely}, ~~\epsilon'=\delta_\epsilon/8=\delta_{0.1}/8=0.08/8=0.01$$

So, for this "new-epsilon" $\epsilon'$, you need to find another "new-delta" $\delta_{\epsilon'}=\delta_{0.01}$

In this case, you need to update above inequality to:

$$-2\epsilon'<\delta_{\epsilon'}/2<2\epsilon'$$

So there is no contradiction. Remember when update, you need to update both $\epsilon\rightarrow\epsilon'$ and correspondingly, $\delta_\epsilon\rightarrow\delta_{\epsilon'}$, so you still get "$\epsilon-\delta_\epsilon $" (or "$\epsilon'-\delta_{\epsilon'}$") pairs.

Your confusion is due to mess up the pairs, what you did is "$\epsilon'-\delta_\epsilon$", and this is where the mistake comes from.

Comment: Very right! Take $f(x)=\frac {3x}{5}$ as an example. We have  $-\epsilon \lt \frac {3x}{5} \lt \epsilon$ for any $x \in \left( \frac{-5\epsilon}{3}, \frac{5\epsilon}{3}  \right )$. That is $\delta_{\epsilon}=\frac{5\epsilon}{3} $. So when you come to $-2\epsilon \lt \frac {\delta_\epsilon}{2} \lt 2\epsilon$, it is the same as $-2\epsilon \lt \frac{5\epsilon}{6} \lt 2\epsilon$. This is certainly true. But when you new $\epsilon$ becomes $\frac {\delta}{8}$ , your new $\delta_{\epsilon}$ has to  change into $\frac{5}{3} \times \frac {\delta}{8}$ accordingly.

Comment: exactly @LiKwokKeung